# how to avoid immutation in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a problem with a mutation I can't understand, here is my code :

```
const copyItems = Object.assign({}, state.items);

for(const typeItems of Object.values(copyItems[0])){
    for(let items of typeItems){
        if(items.id === action.item.id){
            Object.assign(items, action.item);
        }
    }
}

return state.items;
```

I also tried by using `const copyItems = state.items.slice().map(o => ({...o})` but even by returning the state the value is modified. Why?

Comment: What error do you get when you run this code?

Comment: No error but my component is updated when it shouldn't be since I did nothing except returning the initial state

Comment: you can deep clone the object and work with it, if you object are tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `state.items` is a nested object. Then you can do these ways:

```
const newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

follow this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone)

or you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep)

```
const newObj = _.cloneDeep(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `copyItems` copies the `state.items` that would have the same reference.

```js
const copyItems = Object.assign({}, state.items);
```

Then you are mutating the `state.items` when you do the following.

```js
Object.assign(items, action.item);
```

The answer from @bird may work but you will into problem with if you have circular structure or if the object has references to other objects then you will lose all those references. But it really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Using `Object.assign` seems dangerous in terms of functional programming required by Redux. Should be fine if you use it on empty object (`Object.assign({}, ...)`) but not on an existing object.

I have an example code below that might help you case.

```js
const state = {items:[{id:0,value:"default"},{id:1,value:"default"}]};
const action = {item:{id:0,value:"new"}};
const copyItems = state.items.map(o => o.id === action.item.id ? action.item : o);

console.log(state.items, copyItems);
```